# Closed, Compact in Metric Space

Tags: analysis

I have a concept to clarify:

I understand that if we have a compact subset in a metric space, then it is closed (and bounded).

If we have a closed and bounded subset of a metric space, can we also always guarantee that it is compact?

Answer (score 0):

The first is true. In any topological spaces the compact sets are closed and bounded. But the converse is not true in general. For example, if $X$ is an infinite dimensional normed space, then the unit ball of it is closed and bounded while it is not compact.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ as a metric space of $(\mathbb Q,|\;.|)$

It is closed , bounded but not compact (because not complete).

---

You should know that Closed+Bounded implies Compact in any finite-dimensional normed space.

Moreover, a useful theorem : a normed space $E$ has finite dimension iff its unit ball is compact.